# strncpy_s does not respect the standard?

Tags: c++, strncpy

I have this code working fine with Visual Studio 2010:

```
std::string s = "Ceci est le test du StrnCpy";
char buffer_standard[5];
strncpy( buffer_standard, s.c_str(), 5 );
assert( strncmp( buffer_standard, "Ceci ", 5 ) == 0 );
```

But, compiler reports that strncpy is insecure, because I don't want to set _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS (because they may be right, it's insecure), I try to use the MSDN strncpy_s version. **But it does not behave the same way!!!**

- **First difference:**

This raises an assertion (buffer too small), so you have to adapt the size parameter:

```
std::string s = "Ceci est le test du StrnCpy";
char buffer_msdn[5];
strncpy_s( buffer_msdn, s.c_str(), 5 );
```

So I tried this, but then buffer_msdn[4] is '\0' instead of ' ':

```
std::string s = "Ceci est le test du StrnCpy";
char buffer_msdn[5];
strncpy_s( buffer_msdn, s.c_str(), 5-1 );
assert( strncmp( buffer_msdn, "Ceci ", 5 ) == 0 ); // asserts!
```

And this fails the same way:

```
strncpy_s( buffer_msdn, sc.c_str(), _TRUNCATE );
```

- **Second difference:**

The way extra characters are handled is different:

```
std::string s = "Ceci";
char buffer_standard[20];
strncpy( buffer_standard, s.c_str(), 20 );

char buffer_msdn[20];
strncpy_s( buffer_msdn, s.c_str(), s.size() );
```

`buffer_standard` is "Ceci" followed by 16 '\0' 
`buffer_msdn` is "Ceci" followed by only one '\0' (then it's garbage)

So, how does Microsoft expects us to replace strncpy by strncpy_s with the same behaviour???

Comment: `strncpy_s` is not part of The Standard (C++ or C). That's the whole point. They wanted something with different ("safer") behaviour than anything in The Standard. Only you can decide if the behaviour and guarantees they offer suit your needs.

Comment: In particular, they wanted to guarantee that the string that comes out of it is always null-terminated, which makes the first difference.

Comment: I understand they wanted it safer, but they could have make it "safer" AND "standard"....as they did for strcpy_s....I'd like to know if it's made on purpose, or if it's a bug....

Comment: @BoBTFish It made it into C11, did it not?

Comment: @hvd It would appear so, albeit as an optional extension (Annex K). I didn't check The Standard straight away, just searched on cppreference, and it didn't come up. (It is there on the [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) page, but doesn't show up with a [search](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=strncpy_s).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does Microsoft expects us to replace `strncpy` by `strncpy_s` with the same behaviour?

If they had the same behaviour, they'd inescapably have the same security issue: potential lack of termination.  The parameters accepted by `strncpy` prioritorised copying more source data over `NUL` termination, and the new functions basically consider cases where that choice would be significant to warrant warnings prompting:

- a code change to either:

  - show the programmer's happy for one less source characters to be copied or,
  - resize the destination buffer to accept an extra character, else
- a move to another function such as `memcpy` (which may need an extra prior call to `strlen()` or `.size()`) or sticking with `strncpy` (perhaps with `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`).

As these functions are specifically in support of ASCIIZ strings - wherein only one trailing `NUL` is mandated - the inconvenience of occasional use of the last option's evidently considered acceptable.

Comment: So your conclusion is that there is no easy way to safely replace a call to `strncpy` by `strncpy_s`, even if it's possible to easily replace a call to `strcpy` by a call to `strcpy_s` (you just have to add a parameter but behaviours are unchanged)

Comment: @jpo38: that's right: perhaps it would help to ask yourself what behaviour you would give `strncpy_jpo` if it was meant to be a drop-in safe replacement for `strncpy`: you can't win as some of your callers will have been written to cope with a potentially unterminated buffer, others will have already increased their buffer size and argument to ensure all the non-NUL characters they want will be copied, and others still may actually be buggy.  As the `strncpy_jpo`-implementer you can't tell which is which, which is why MS force disambiguating code changes.

Comment: OK, it makes sense. `strncpy_jpo` will most likely have an extra parameter to tell what behaviour is expected....;-)